# Symfony Form: DoctrineChoice makes every value null

Tags: forms, doctrine, symfony1

I have a little Problem with symfony 1.4(.16): i have a pretty basic schema:

```
Creature:
  columns:
    UniqueName: { type: string }
    CleanName:  { type: string }
    RegionType: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    UserLevel: { type: integer }
  relations:
    RegionType: { local: RegionType, foreign: id, foreignAlias: CreatureRegion, onDelete: CASCADE}
```

the rest is not really important...

I have an automatically generated admin... the form has all values of the RegionType in a list.. that works fine... but when saving, suddently the value becomes "NULL"... it passes the validator and gets null after that... i tried with implicite "notnull:true", but now only the sql returns an error that the value is null, so it must not be null when passing the validator...

any ideas what this could be?

Comment: What version of symfony do you use?Maybe try instead of integer make integer() in your **RegionType** field in your Creature table and RegionType table.

Comment: i used 1.4.13, tried to upgrade to 1.4.16 but that didnt solve it

Comment: Did you try to make  integer() instead of  integer ?)

Comment: yeah, i tried that, didn't change anything... i ended up overwriting the autogenerated processForm and doing the Validation manually... could not find another solution...

Comment: You can't have a field with the same name as a relation "RegionType"... you must use somthing like:
Field: region_type_id; Relation: RegionType.

Answer (score -1):

Try to underscore your fields names instead of camelcasing them. This case is not conventional, it may cause your problem...